# LaTeX: Specifying default document-wide font

Tags: latex, fonts

For some fonts, it's easy to replace the default font with something like: `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{somefont}`.

However, some fonts, like [BrushScriptX](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/brushscriptx/)
want you to use a special command like `\bsifamily` to use the font. In the

`\bsifamily` is defined in /usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/brushscr/pbsi.sty:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\bsifamily{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pbsi}%
  \fontseries{xl}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
```

In this case, I have a document that uses a cls stylesheet that I am editing. I'm using the standard includes to use this font:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pbsi}
```

If I try to use `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{bpsi}` in my document's template, it fails with the error: Font shape `T1/pbsi/m/n' undefined

What might be the best way to replace the default roman font with BrushScriptX in a template, like `\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{otherfont}` would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look inside `pbsi.sty` you'll find

```
\DeclareRobustCommand\bsifamily{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{pbsi}%
  \fontseries{xl}\fontshape{n}\selectfont}
```

Therefore, to set this font as the default — ugh `:)` — you'll need to write

```
\renewcommand\rmdefault{pbsi}
\renewcommand\mddefault{xl}
```

(`\mddefault` is the default "non-bold" series used in running text.)

Comment: P.S.  I had no idea this font existed (not that I'd ever gone looking). No wonder TeX Live is multi-GB to download, although documentation is a large chunk of the total...

Comment: Thanks! With what you said and `\renewcommand\bfdefault{xl}`, it worked. Rest at ease - I'm not going to actually use that font in particular; it was just an example that I could get working so that I could see how several different fonts look in this document.